# XDoclet classpath missing J2EE classes (MyEclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, myeclipse, xdoclet

I cannot find a solution to this problem.

When I try to run ejbdoclet, I get the error

```
XDoclet classpath missing J2EE classes
```

Where is the XDoclet classpath and where are the J2EE classes it's missing? Does anyone here have any ideas? I'm using MyEclipse and Ant.

Full trace:

```
[ejbdoclet] XDoclet classpath missing J2EE classes
[ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask.validateOptions(EjbDocletTask.java:86)
[ejbdoclet]     at xjavadoc.ant.XJavadocTask.execute(XJavadocTask.java:89)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ejbdoclet]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ejbdoclet]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
[ejbdoclet] Caused by: Make sure the jar file containing the javax.ejb.EntityBean class is on the classpath specified in the <taskdef> that defined ejbdoclet. These classes are needed in order to generate correct output.
[ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.DocletTask.checkClass(DocletTask.java:513)
[ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask.validateOptions(EjbDocletTask.java:83)
[ejbdoclet]     ... 31 more

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: here's a similar problem, with a work-around soln.: http://www.myeclipseide.com/PNphpBB2-viewtopic-t-4105.html

Comment: If that doesn't help, it would be useful to include as much detail as possible (such as, but not only) the myeclipse release, OS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing some jar files in your path or your path in the build.xml is wrong.  Check your build.xml.
I had a similar problem but realized I had a typo in the path.

```
<pathelement location="${resin.home}/lib/ejb-15.jar" />
<pathelement location="${resin.home}/lib/ejb-20.jar" />
<pathelement location="${resin.home}/lib/ejb-30.jar" />
<pathelement location="${build}"/>
```

I had my resin.home pointing to a wrong location.
I got the following error:

```
[ejbdoclet] XDoclet classpath missing J2EE classes
[ejbdoclet]     at xdoclet.modules.ejb.EjbDocletTask.validateOptions(EjbDocletTask.java:86)
[ejbdoclet]     at xjavadoc.ant.XJavadocTask.execute(XJavadocTask.java:89)
[ejbdoclet]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ejbdoclet]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ejbdoclet]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
```